# How can I add a product SKU field to the search filter for the orders view?

Tags: views, commerce

In the administrator interface, there is an *Orders* view which shows all orders. Within this view, I would like to add a *Product SKU* field to the search filter.

On the edit form for the Orders view, I clicked on the *Add* button shown for *Advanced » Relationship*, but I can't find any product or product variation entity there.

How can I add a product SKU field to the search filter for the orders view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you all most did it !

first in the view  you need to add the "Order item referenced from order_items" relationship

in your view ->advanced RELATIONSHIPS...

after this you can then add the "Product variation" relationship.

with the 2 relationships added to the view you can now add the exposed filter you require.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working for me now.

Comment: thank you, made it work for me as well, in Ubercart. Just requires the two relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to comment on here about what to do if you're using the D7 version and come across this post (like we did). Here's the two relationships you will need to add in order to have SKU as a filter:

Commerce Order: Referenced line items

Commerce Line item: Referenced products